# navigate('DrawerOpen') not working with createSwitchNavigator and createStackNavigator

Tags: react-native, native-base

Please check this [expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/BJ6eQMjQQ).

I have a switch-navigator for logged-in and not-logged-in states.

When user is logged in, switcher loads a `DrawerNavigator` which loads `Screen1` and loads the sidebar (SideBar.js) via `contentComponent`

Inside `Screen1` I'm calling the `this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen');` via the `onPress` event of the menu burger button. But it's not opening the drawer. What am I doing wroing

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You call in a screen which isn't contained in `DrawerNavigation`, so it can't navigate. To open drawer in anywhere just use

```
import { DrawerActions } from 'react-navigation';
...
openDrawer = () => {
  this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());
}
...
```

Comment: to which page should i add this line... either App.js or Screen1?

Comment: undefined is not an object (this.props.navigation) !

Comment: Now, DrawerActions should be imported from 'react-navigation-drawer'.

Answer (score 6):

use this:

```
this.props.navigation.openDrawer();
```

Answer (score 0):

In `React Navigation 3.x`, you can use `this.props.navigation.openDrawer();` to open the drawer in `CreateDrawerNavigator`. It is the same as using `this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());`.
You can checkout the official docs here : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-based-navigation.html